# In SparkR 1.5.0, how do we specify a column unambiguously after a join on common column?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I joined two dataframes on a column with same name.

```
oe = join(orders, emp, orders$EmployeeID == emp$EmployeeID)
```

The resulting dataframe has two columns with same name `EmployeeID`

Now a group by or even printing column name

```
peremp = groupBy(oe, 'EmployeeID', sales = n(oe$OrderID))
oe$EmployeeID
```

fails with the error

> Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) :
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'EmployeeID' is
>   ambiguous, could be: EmployeeID#36, EmployeeID#69.;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access columns through parent data frame. First lets create some example data:

```
df1 <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3), v=c("a", "b", "c")))
df2 <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(id=c(2, 3), v=c("g", "z")))
df <- join(df1, df2, df1$id == df2$id)
head(df)
##   id v id v
## 1  3 c  3 z
## 2  2 b  2 g
```

And access `v` column:

```
select(df, "v")
## 15/09/30 17:47:13 ERROR RBackendHandler: select on 131 failed
## Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) : 
##   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'v' is ambiguous, could be
## ....

select(df, df1$v) %>% head
##   v
## 1 c
## 2 b
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple workaround seems to be renaming the column in one of the tables beforehand with the withColumnRenamed function. The other approach I would try is figuring out the position from the columns function and then dropping the column, but I don't see a way that obviously works.

Comment: There is no need for workarounds. You can simply access columns using `$` function on the parent data frame.